# I need to pick the Top of Stack in the peci xml

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, stack, row

```
enter code here
```

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <peci:Summary>
        <peci:Integration_Event>556a0625852810035876d2d1aa340000</peci:Integration_Event>
        <peci:Integration_Sent_On>2022-07-05T17:16:48.710-07:00</peci:Integration_Sent_On>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>CUSTOM_ORGANIZATION-6-121</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>India Payroll</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Code>INDPAY</peci:Payroll_Company_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Group_ID>PG_India_Pay_Group</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Name>India Pay Group</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>IN</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code/>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>2022-07-01-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>2022-07-31-07:00</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>2022-05-05T14:45:13.000-07:00</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>2022-07-05T17:16:48.710-07:00</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>2022-07-01-07:00</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>2022-07-31-07:00</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful
            run.</peci:Change_Detection>
        <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
        <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>
        <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>
    </peci:Summary>
    <peci:Worker>
        <peci:Worker_Summary>
            <peci:WID>034e29aefd0e1012e7328dbe7bd30000</peci:WID>
            <peci:Employee_ID>100879</peci:Employee_ID>
            <peci:Name>Test India Employee</peci:Name>
        </peci:Worker_Summary>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-06-27T00:00:00.000-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-06-23T09:32:01.312-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Status peci:isAdded="1">Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active peci:priorValue="0">1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date peci:isAdded="1">2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date peci:isAdded="1">2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Personal peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Legal_Name>
                    <peci:First_Name>Test 0</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>India Employee 0</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Gender>Male</peci:Gender>
                <peci:Date_of_Birth>2000-02-01-08:00</peci:Date_of_Birth>
                <peci:Marital_Status>IND_Married 0</peci:Marital_Status>
                <peci:Nationality>IN</peci:Nationality>
            </peci:Personal>
            <peci:Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Test 123</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>Bangalore</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>125447</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>IN</peci:Country>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Email peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>test.india.ee@test.uni.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
            <peci:Person_Identification peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:National_Identifier peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:National_ID>2454 6445 6511</peci:National_ID>
                    <peci:National_ID_Type>AADHAR_IN</peci:National_ID_Type>
                </peci:National_Identifier>
                <peci:Other_Identifier peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:Custom_ID>UNI1000074711</peci:Custom_ID>
                    <peci:Custom_ID_Type>UNI_ID</peci:Custom_ID_Type>
                </peci:Other_Identifier>
            </peci:Person_Identification>
            <peci:Related_Person peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Related_Person_ID>034e29aefd0e1012e91c7b197de60000</peci:Related_Person_ID>
                <peci:Legal_Name>
                    <peci:First_Name>Test</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>Father</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
            </peci:Related_Person>
            <peci:Related_Person peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Related_Person_ID>034e29aefd0e1012e95cdb3029d10001</peci:Related_Person_ID>
                <peci:Legal_Name>
                    <peci:First_Name>Test</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>EC</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Relationship_Type>Spouse</peci:Relationship_Type>
            </peci:Related_Person>
            <peci:Position peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Business_Title>Analyst</peci:Business_Title>
                <peci:Worker_Type>Regular</peci:Worker_Type>
                <peci:Supervisor>
                    <peci:ID>100547</peci:ID>
                    <peci:Name>Sayuri Dimitroff Frost</peci:Name>
                </peci:Supervisor>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>DIV_100_Core_U_Product</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Division</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>U Product</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>CC_9100_People</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>9100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>People</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>COM_Flora_Software_Systems_Private_Limited</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Company</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>Flora Software Systems Private
                        Limited</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
            </peci:Position>
            <peci:Compensation peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay>8333.33</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>0</peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>
                    <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                    <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
            <peci:Compensation_Plans peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Bonus_Plan>
                    <peci:Compensation_Plan>Flora Corporate Bonus Plan</peci:Compensation_Plan>
                    <peci:Amount>10000</peci:Amount>
                    <peci:Percentage>0.1</peci:Percentage>
                    <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                    <peci:Frequency>Annual</peci:Frequency>
                    <peci:Start_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Start_Date>
                    <peci:Compensation_Element>Flora Corporate Bonus
                        Plan</peci:Compensation_Element>
                </peci:Bonus_Plan>
            </peci:Compensation_Plans>
            <peci:Payment_Election peci:isAdded="1">
                <peci:Order>1</peci:Order>
                <peci:Payment_Type>Direct Deposit</peci:Payment_Type>
                <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                <peci:Account_Number>1342534656456</peci:Account_Number>
                <peci:Account_Type>DDA</peci:Account_Type>
                <peci:Bank_Name>bank</peci:Bank_Name>
                <peci:Bank_ID>12345678901</peci:Bank_ID>
                <peci:Distribution_Balance>1</peci:Distribution_Balance>
            </peci:Payment_Election>
            <peci:Additional_Information peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:WorkerID>034e29aefd0e1012e7328dbe7bd30000</peci:WorkerID>
                <ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf" peci:isAdded="1"
                    >UNI2404012</ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID>
                <ptdf:Manager_First_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf" peci:isAdded="1"
                    >Sayuri</ptdf:Manager_First_Name>
                <ptdf:Manager_Last_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf" peci:isAdded="1"
                    >Frost</ptdf:Manager_Last_Name>
                <ptdf:Location xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf" peci:priorValue="LOC_IN_Remote"
                    >LOC_IN_Bangalore</ptdf:Location>
            </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="7">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-05T16:24:27.365-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-05T16:24:27.365-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Personal>
                <peci:Legal_Name>
                    <peci:First_Name>Test</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>India Employee</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Gender>Male</peci:Gender>
                <peci:Date_of_Birth>2002-02-01-08:00</peci:Date_of_Birth>
                <peci:Marital_Status>IND_Married</peci:Marital_Status>
                <peci:Nationality>IN</peci:Nationality>
            </peci:Personal>
            <peci:Person_Communication>
                <peci:Address>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Test 123</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>Bangalore</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>125447</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>IN</peci:Country>
                    <peci:State_Province>Karnataka</peci:State_Province>
                    <peci:Usage>
                        <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>Permanent</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                    </peci:Usage>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Phone>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Phone_Device_Type>Landline</peci:Phone_Device_Type>
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>97674</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>98765</peci:Phone_Number>
                    <peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>+91 (97674)
                        98765</peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>
                </peci:Phone>
                <peci:Phone>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Phone_Device_Type>Mobile</peci:Phone_Device_Type>
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>97887</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>50987</peci:Phone_Number>
                    <peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>+91 (97887)
                        50987</peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>
                </peci:Phone>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>test.newhire@Flora.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>test.india.ee@test.uni.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
            <peci:Person_Identification>
                <peci:National_Identifier>
                    <peci:National_ID>2454 6445 6511</peci:National_ID>
                    <peci:National_ID_Type>AADHAR_IN</peci:National_ID_Type>
                </peci:National_Identifier>
                <peci:Other_Identifier>
                    <peci:Custom_ID>UNI1000074711</peci:Custom_ID>
                    <peci:Custom_ID_Type>UNI_ID</peci:Custom_ID_Type>
                </peci:Other_Identifier>
            </peci:Person_Identification>
            <peci:Related_Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Related_Person_ID>034e29aefd0e1012e95cdb3029d10001</peci:Related_Person_ID>
                <peci:Phone peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>72245</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>68098</peci:Phone_Number>
                </peci:Phone>
            </peci:Related_Person_Communication>
            <peci:Position>
                <peci:Business_Title>Sr. HR Technology Analyst</peci:Business_Title>
                <peci:Worker_Type>Regular</peci:Worker_Type>
                <peci:Supervisor>
                    <peci:ID>100547</peci:ID>
                    <peci:Name>Sayuri Dimitroff Frost</peci:Name>
                </peci:Supervisor>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>DIV_100_Core_U_Product</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Division</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>U Product</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>CC_9100_People</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>9100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>People</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>COM_Flora_Software_Systems_Private_Limited</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Company</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>Flora Software Systems Private
                        Limited</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
            </peci:Position>
            <peci:Compensation>
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay>8333.33</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>0</peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>
                    <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                    <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
            <peci:Payment_Election>
                <peci:Order>1</peci:Order>
                <peci:Payment_Type>Direct Deposit</peci:Payment_Type>
                <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                <peci:Bank_Account_Name>Test Account</peci:Bank_Account_Name>
                <peci:Account_Number>123456789</peci:Account_Number>
                <peci:Account_Type>SA</peci:Account_Type>
                <peci:Bank_Name>Indian Bank</peci:Bank_Name>
                <peci:Bank_ID>IFSC1234456</peci:Bank_ID>
                <peci:BIC>IDIBINBB123</peci:BIC>
                <peci:Distribution_Balance>1</peci:Distribution_Balance>
            </peci:Payment_Election>
            <peci:Additional_Information>
                <peci:WorkerID>034e29aefd0e1012e7328dbe7bd30000</peci:WorkerID>
                <ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >UNI2404012</ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID>
                <ptdf:Manager_First_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >Sayuri</ptdf:Manager_First_Name>
                <ptdf:Manager_Last_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >Frost</ptdf:Manager_Last_Name>
                <ptdf:Location xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >LOC_IN_Bangalore</ptdf:Location>
            </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
        <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="5">
            <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
            <peci:Effective_Moment>2022-07-05T16:24:27.365-07:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
            <peci:Entry_Moment>2022-07-05T16:24:27.365-07:00</peci:Entry_Moment>
            <peci:Worker_Status>
                <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
                <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
                <peci:Active_Status_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Active_Status_Date>
                <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>
                <peci:Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Hire_Date>
                <peci:Original_Hire_Date>2022-06-27-07:00</peci:Original_Hire_Date>
            </peci:Worker_Status>
            <peci:Personal>
                <peci:Legal_Name>
                    <peci:First_Name>Test5</peci:First_Name>
                    <peci:Last_Name>India Employee5</peci:Last_Name>
                </peci:Legal_Name>
                <peci:Gender>Male</peci:Gender>
                <peci:Date_of_Birth>2001-02-01-08:00</peci:Date_of_Birth>
                <peci:Marital_Status>IND_Divorced</peci:Marital_Status>
                <peci:Nationality>IN</peci:Nationality>
            </peci:Personal>
            <peci:Person_Communication>
                <peci:Address>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Address_Line_1>Test 123</peci:Address_Line_1>
                    <peci:City>Bangalore</peci:City>
                    <peci:Postal_Code>125447</peci:Postal_Code>
                    <peci:Country>IN</peci:Country>
                    <peci:State_Province>Karnataka</peci:State_Province>
                    <peci:Usage>
                        <peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>Permanent</peci:Usage_Behavior_ID>
                    </peci:Usage>
                </peci:Address>
                <peci:Phone>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Phone_Device_Type>Landline</peci:Phone_Device_Type>
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>97674</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>98765</peci:Phone_Number>
                    <peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>+91 (97674)
                        98765</peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>
                </peci:Phone>
                <peci:Phone>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Phone_Device_Type>Mobile</peci:Phone_Device_Type>
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>97887</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>50987</peci:Phone_Number>
                    <peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>+91 (97887)
                        50987</peci:Phone_Number_With_Country_Code>
                </peci:Phone>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>test.newhire@Flora.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
                <peci:Email>
                    <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
                    <peci:Email_Address>test.india.ee@test.uni.com</peci:Email_Address>
                </peci:Email>
            </peci:Person_Communication>
            <peci:Person_Identification>
                <peci:National_Identifier>
                    <peci:National_ID>2454 6445 6511</peci:National_ID>
                    <peci:National_ID_Type>AADHAR_IN</peci:National_ID_Type>
                </peci:National_Identifier>
                <peci:Other_Identifier>
                    <peci:Custom_ID>UNI1000074711</peci:Custom_ID>
                    <peci:Custom_ID_Type>UNI_ID</peci:Custom_ID_Type>
                </peci:Other_Identifier>
            </peci:Person_Identification>
            <peci:Related_Person_Communication peci:isUpdated="1">
                <peci:Related_Person_ID>034e29aefd0e1012e95cdb3029d10001</peci:Related_Person_ID>
                <peci:Phone peci:isAdded="1">
                    <peci:International_Phone_Code>91</peci:International_Phone_Code>
                    <peci:Area_Code>72245</peci:Area_Code>
                    <peci:Phone_Number>68098</peci:Phone_Number>
                </peci:Phone>
            </peci:Related_Person_Communication>
            <peci:Position>
                <peci:Business_Title>Technology Analyst</peci:Business_Title>
                <peci:Worker_Type>Regular</peci:Worker_Type>
                <peci:Supervisor>
                    <peci:ID>100547</peci:ID>
                    <peci:Name>Sayuri Dimitroff Frost</peci:Name>
                </peci:Supervisor>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>DIV_100_Core_U_Product</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Division</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>U Product</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>CC_9100_People</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Code>9100</peci:Organization_Code>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>People</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
                <peci:Organization>
                    <peci:Organization_ID>COM_Flora_Software_Systems_Private_Limited</peci:Organization_ID>
                    <peci:Organization_Type>Company</peci:Organization_Type>
                    <peci:Organization_Name>Flora Software Systems Private
                        Limited</peci:Organization_Name>
                </peci:Organization>
            </peci:Position>
            <peci:Compensation>
                <peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
                    <peci:Total_Base_Pay>8333.33</peci:Total_Base_Pay>
                    <peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>0</peci:Primary_Compensation_Basis>
                    <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                    <peci:Frequency>Monthly</peci:Frequency>
                </peci:Compensation_Summary_in_Pay_Group_Frequency>
            </peci:Compensation>
            <peci:Payment_Election>
                <peci:Order>1</peci:Order>
                <peci:Payment_Type>Direct Deposit</peci:Payment_Type>
                <peci:Currency>INR</peci:Currency>
                <peci:Bank_Account_Name>Test Account</peci:Bank_Account_Name>
                <peci:Account_Number>123456789</peci:Account_Number>
                <peci:Account_Type>SA</peci:Account_Type>
                <peci:Bank_Name>Indian Bank</peci:Bank_Name>
                <peci:Bank_ID>IFSC1234456</peci:Bank_ID>
                <peci:BIC>IDIBINBB123</peci:BIC>
                <peci:Distribution_Balance>1</peci:Distribution_Balance>
            </peci:Payment_Election>
            <peci:Additional_Information>
                <peci:WorkerID>034e29aefd0e1012e7328dbe7bd30000</peci:WorkerID>
                <ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >UNI2404012</ptdf:Manager_Flora_ID>
                <ptdf:Manager_First_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >Sayuri</ptdf:Manager_First_Name>
                <ptdf:Manager_Last_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >Frost</ptdf:Manager_Last_Name>
                <ptdf:Location xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf"
                    >LOC_IN_Bangalore</ptdf:Location>
            </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
</peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
```

So in this case there might be more sequence but i need to fetch the latest sequence
could any help in this regard .

I tried sorting the sequence number and passing the sequence number to the attribute to get the latest row but it seems to fetch all the rows

Now i have update my xml with 3 peci sequence

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the latest item by the attribute value "Sequence" , you can use this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="text()" />

  <xsl:template match="/peci:Workers_Effective_Stack/peci:Worker">
    <xsl:for-each select="peci:Effective_Change">
      <xsl:sort select="@peci:Sequence" order="descending"/>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Legal_Name/peci:First_Name" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
        <xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Legal_Name/peci:Last_Name" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>   
        <xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Date_of_Birth" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
        <xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Marital_Status" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
        <xsl:value-of select="peci:Position/peci:Business_Title" /><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>          
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
Test
India Employee
2002-02-01-08:00
IND_Married
Sr. HR Technology Analyst
```

*This stylesheet could be simplified by using higher versions like XSLT-2.0 or XSLT-3.0, but you did not specify that you can use these versions, so I assumed the lowest common denominator.*

Comment: Thank you , I tried using Last() but it picks the Last row and does not sort by sequence number for eg if the Last row sequence number is  5 then this code will bring  data for Sequence 5 but ideally it should pick the sequence of 7 which is the highest sequence .

Comment: I added an approach ordering by the attribute "Effective_Change".

Comment: BTW your XML file is inconsistent: the first `peci:Effective_Change`  element has an attribute `peci:Sequence`, but the second has an attribute `peci:Effective_Change`. Is this intended or an error? Or do you want to sort based on the first attribute of the element `peci:Effective_Change`?

Comment: yes now i updated the xml to bring 3 sequences it should be sorted on peci:Sequence

Comment: I updated my answer. It should give you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

if you need max *Sequence = 7*

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" exclude-result-prefixes="peci">

<xsl:variable name="maxseq" select="max(.//peci:Effective_Change/@peci:Sequence)"/>
<!-- <xsl:variable name="lastseq" select="(.//peci:Effective_Change/@peci:Sequence)[last()]"/>-->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//peci:Effective_Change[@peci:Sequence=$maxseq]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="peci:Effective_Change[@peci:Sequence=$maxseq]">
    <First_Name><xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Legal_Name/peci:First_Name"/></First_Name>
    <Last_Name><xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Legal_Name/peci:Last_Name"/></Last_Name>
    <Date_of_Birth><xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Date_of_Birth"/></Date_of_Birth>
    <Marital_Status><xsl:value-of select="peci:Personal/peci:Marital_Status"/></Marital_Status>
    <Business_Title><xsl:value-of select="peci:Position/peci:Business_Title"/></Business_Title>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it'll produce

```
<First_Name>Test</First_Name>
<Last_Name>India Employee</Last_Name>
<Date_of_Birth>2002-02-01-08:00</Date_of_Birth>
<Marital_Status>IND_Married</Marital_Status>
<Business_Title>Sr. HR Technology Analyst</Business_Title>
```

if you need last *Sequence = 5*  then uncomment the variable *lastseq* declaration and change *maxseq* in the code to it and it'll produce

```
<First_Name>Test5</First_Name>
<Last_Name>India Employee5</Last_Name>
<Date_of_Birth>2001-02-01-08:00</Date_of_Birth>
<Marital_Status>IND_Divorced</Marital_Status>
<Business_Title>Technology Analyst</Business_Title>
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy that was working perfect